# Fresh Python 3.9 install is making no sense with pip in Windows 10 (Unable to create process)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, path

So, I was having some problems with installing new libraries via pip, so I decided to do a fresh install of Python. I uninstalled it and removed everything related to it, and reinstalled it via the official 3.9.6 64-bit Windows installer. Upon install, I rebooted my PC so the %PATH% changes would take effect, and to my surprise pip is not working. The error message is as follows:

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified.`

And this path makes absolutely no sense, since a `where python` query returns `C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`. Upon inspection, the path cited by the error does indeed exist, but it's just a version of the `where python` directory but without the executables. This path did not exist before so I sincerely don't understand. [These are all the directories listed in my %PATH% variable](http://prntscr.com/1kgcelq), which includes the actual location where the pip executable is included. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Well to begin with, the image you posted appears to have a duplicate entry, which should not be there, and I would consider it badly ordered too. However, all you've shown us is the content of your User Environment variable named `Path`, we also need to see the content of your System Environment `Path` variable. The `%Path%` variable is a concatenated variable containing both of those, System first, then User, and executables are searched in that order first to last, executing the first match found. Also when you uninstall something included in `%Path%`, I doubt it would remove that entry too!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem. The Python installer seems to have only included itself in a %PATH% variable that exists for the only user in my computer instead of the system-wide %PATH% variable.

Comment: That is an install option. The installer asks which you want.